# What is the equivalent tag of Hibernate Annotation @NotFound(action=NotFoundAction.IGNORE) in XML based configuration?

Tags: hibernate

The hibernate setup of project is XML based. 
The system is throwing error as org.hibernate.ObjectNotFoundException: No row with the given identifier exists:
In order to resolve this i want to use tag which is equivalent to above annotation for the property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use in xml configuration like below.

```
<many-to-one ... not-found="ignore" />
```

Comment: Apologies for seeing the solution late.